# website preprocessor to embed .css files into .html files

Tags: linux, html, css, web-server, static-site-generator

I'm looking for a tool that will embed `link` CSS files into the `.html` file.

This tool would scan the `.html` file. It would replace a line like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
```

with the contents of the file `main.css` (wrapped in a `<style>` element).  It would re-write the `.html` file with the embedded CSS code from file `main.css`.

I have found tools that "inline" the CSS within HTML elements (`<div style="...">`). These are intended for email. I do not want those tools.
I want a tool that would copy the CSS file into a single `<style>` element within the `.html` file.

This tool should have a CLI, run on Linux, and be free (no payments, no shareware).

Comment: @Izzy Linux.  Free.  Updated the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Added the `linux` tag for better discovery (`gratis` tag no longer fits due to max-tags=5). Good luck! Cleaning up comments then.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use **Gulp** + **Critical** extension.

It's a free cross platform CLI tool. And it allows to extract critical CSS and either embed it into HTML file or extract it to another CSS file.

When you get to configuring your `gulpfile.js`, here's mine which I've used while testing this:

```
const gulp          = require('gulp');
const critical      = require('critical').stream;
function inline(cb) {
    return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
    .pipe(critical({
        inline: true,
        base: './src',
        width: 320,
        height: 480,
        minify: false
    }))
    .on('error', function(err) { log.error(err.message); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
exports.inline = inline;
```

When you run `gulp inline` it analyses your index.html file and creates a copy of it in `dist` directory, but with critical CSS inlined and extra JS for asynchronous loading.

See a [nice Gulp tutorial](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/use-gulp-automate-your-critical-path-css/) and [Critical documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical) for more examples and info.

Note: This requires getting hang of Gulp first if you are not familiar with it yet.

Comment: _Gulp_ looks very powerful.  But I am a javascript newbie so using _gulp_ will be a challenging learning experience.  Thanks @Oleg!